# Multiple User Foreign Keys to Same Model?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm attempting to create a simple web application (first django personal project) for my friends and I to log our casual sporting bets against eachother. Currently I have the model like this using django's auth User model:

```
class Bet(models.Model):
    bettor1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bettor2 = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    bet_description = models.TextField()
    bet_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    win_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Currently bettor1 is correctly linked to the user that is logged into the application, but I would like to make it so that bettor 2 is also a foreign key (i think?) connecting to another user's account that exists on the application. (So bettor 1 can choose the opponent he is wagering against from a dropdown menu of the other users with existing accounts). How can I do this?

On top of this, I would like to add a "winner" attribute to eventually set the winner of the bet to be one of the two users, bettor1 and bettor2

Tried setting another foreign key to user but got errors. Not sure how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

I want to set multiple foreign key of same model in Django, you have to set **different** `related_name` for each foreign key.

In your case you make your model like this :

```
class Bet(models.Model):
    bettor1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bets_bettor1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bettor2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bets_bettor2', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bet_description = models.TextField()
    bet_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    win_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

If you have done migrations already, add `blank=True` and `null=True` in foreign key.

```
class Bet(models.Model):
    bettor1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bets_bettor1', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,)
    bettor2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bets_bettor2', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,)
    bet_description = models.TextField()
    bet_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    win_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```